# How to add or remove CSS class of an external library component from our own component in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a component which has an external library component. I want to change toggle one class of external library component based on some condition in my own component. Here thus, I can not use ngClass. I could use document.querySelector but I dont want to use it. Is there any other way?

Comment: IF the external library has been developed by you, you could pass an input to that component that remove that css class.

Comment: No not developed by me. I am using Openlayers and its class needs to be toggled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) in your component class to reference the external library component, configuring ViewChild's `read` option to give you the component as an [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) so you can then toggle the DOM element class.

For example, if the external component in your component's template looks like this:

```html
<div>
  <external-component class="toggle-me"></external-component>
</div>
```

You can attach a template reference variable to it, like so:

```html
<div>
  <external-component #exComp class="toggle-me"></external-component>
  <!--                ^^ add this template reference variable  -->
</div>
```

Then in your component class, use ViewChild to get a hold of the external component using that template reference variable, specifying `{ read: ElementRef }` so you get its DOM element rather than its component class instance:

```js
@ViewChild('exComp', { read: ElementRef }) externalComponent: ElementRef;
```

With that, you can then access the `nativeElement` and its `classList` to toggle the class:

```js
this.externalComponent.nativeElement.classList.toggle('toggle-me');
```

Alternatively, if you didn't want to add a template reference variable, or were not able to, you could pass the external component's class name, rather than the template reference variable name, to ViewChild.

```js
@ViewChild(ExternalComponent, { read: ElementRef }) externalComponent: ElementRef;
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tour-of-heroes-example-material-design-co-k8gukg?file=app/app.component.ts) showing both options.